# Uploading multiple image how to store them

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, yii

Okay so I am doing this project and i need to allow the user the ability to upload 6 images, how should i go by doing this on the database side of things.

- Make a column for each image
- Store it in one column as an array and then do the processing of the array with PHP?

I will be useing the Yii Framework and also MySQL as a database engine.

- I know how to upload file and store it to a directory and the other needed things, just not sure what to tackle the problem.

**EDIT:** My final goal is to have this index page edited by one user (Admin) and I want him to allow him to edit the images and the current offers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create table user_images beacause:

1. You can change number of images pef user in the future without changing database
2. You can easily display all images in GridView and easly generate CRUD for user images.
3. You can easily store versioned list of images for user.
4. Implementation and code reusable  will be simplier.

Comment: Okay makes alot of sense thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new table called "user_images(id, user_id, image_url)" to store image.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that is a good idea, while it still be the best solution in my current situation, i edited the question.